# Scrum - How to get better input from the functional/commercial team

Tags: scrum, methodology, requirements

We are a small team of 3 developers (2 experienced but new to  this particular business sector) developing a functionally complex product.  We're using Scrum and have a demo at the end of each sprint.  Its clear that the functional team have plenty of ideas but these are not well communicated to the development team and the demo poses more questions than answers.

Have you any recommendations for improving the the quality of input from the functional people?

**Further info:** I think part of the problem is that there are no *specs* or  User Stories as such.  Personally I think they need to be writing down some sort of requirements - what sort of things should they be writing down and to what complexity given its an agile process?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried working with your customer to define / formulate **acceptance tests**?
Using something like Fit to come up with these tests - would result in better specs as well as force the customer to think about what is really required. The icing on the cake is instant-doc-executable specs at the end of this process.

That is of course, if your customers are available and open to this approach. Give it a try!

If not (and that seems to be the majority - because it is less work) - calendar flash 'em - schedule meetings/telecons every week until they sing like canaries :) +1 to Dana

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the easiest way to get input from people is to force it out of them.  My company used SCRUM on a project, and found very quickly that people tend to keep to themselves when they already know what they're doing.  We ended up organizing weekly meetings where team members were required to display something that was learned during the week.  It was forced, but it worked pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big believer in Use Cases, detailing the system behaviour in response to user actions.  Collectively these can form a loose set of requirements, and in a SCRUM environment can help you prioritise the Use Cases which will form that particular sprint's implemented features.

For example, after talking to your functional team you identify 15 separate Use Cases.  You prioritise the Use Cases, and decided to plan for 5 sprints.  And the end of each sprint you go through and demo the product fulfilling the Use Cases implemented during the sprint, noting the feedback and amending the Use Cases.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that the people you call functional people are acting as Product Owners, right?

> I think part of the problem is that there are no specs or User Stories as such. Personally I think they need to be writing down some sort of requirements - what sort of things should they be writing down and to what complexity given its an agile process?

Actually, without having any specs you probably have no acceptance test for the backlog itens as well. You should ask the PO to write the user stories, I like the "As a - type of user -, I want -some goal- so that -some reason-." form. Keep in mind that the User Stories shall be INVEST - **I**ndependent, **N**egotiable, **V**aluable to users or customers, **E**stimable, **S**mall and **T**estable. What is a must is to have the Acceptance tests written together with the story so that the team should know what the story must be able to do in order do be set as done.

Remember that as the product evolves, it's expected to the PO have ideas as he sees the working product. It's not a bad thing, actually it is one of the best thing you can get through Agile. What you have to pay attention is that this ideas mus be included in the product backlog and it needs to be prioritized by th PO. And, if it's necessary and will add value to the customer, the idea should be planned to be built in the next sprint.

Comment: Yes.  We're doing the User Stories like you say but currently it's the dev team lead who is writing them from input from the PO. Clearly that is not ideal but for the moment we have no choice.

Like you suggest User Story + Acceptance Test is crucial - I shall look at that - Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Someone from the functional team should be part of the team and available to answer your questions about the features you're adding.

How can you estimate the Backlog item if they are not detailled enough ?

You could establissh a rule that Backlog item that do not have clear acceptance criteria cannot be planned.

If would be better to have someone from the functional team acting as Product Owner, to determine, choose and priotitize the Backlog items, and/or as Domain Expert.

Also, make sure everyone in both the functional team and the development team speaks the same language, so as to avoid misunderstandings ; See [ubiquitous language](http://domaindrivendesign.org/discussion/messageboardarchive/UbiquitousLanguage.html).

Track the time most waiting for answers from the functional team as well as he time wasted developping unnecessary features or reworking existing features so that they fits the bill.

Answer (score 0):

Are they participating in the stand-up meetings?

You could propose to have a representative at each (or some) of them, to ask them for input before the end of the sprint

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing stand-up meetings and do you have burn down chart?  I think those two areas would benefit you greatly.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the book "[Practices of an agile developer](http://pragprog.com/titles/pad/practices-of-an-agile-developer)" it is full of suggestions how to make a scrum team successful. It also gives good tips how to get the product owner/customer more involved and how to get the whole process rolling. It's worth the money IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that you need some sort of requirements (user stories or else).

One piece of advice I can give is to use some sort of visual aids with the functional teams. When customers have plenty of ideas (as you've said) they usually also have a visual idea of what a feature looks like, when the developed product doesn't fit this visual idea it creates a lot of doubts, even if it does the job functionally.

When discussing functionality with customers, I try to be very visual. Drawing sketches on a board, or even verbally describing what something would look like. Trying to find a common visual image. You can then take a photo of the sketches and use them as part of the documentation.

Another advice is to keep your sprints as short as possible, so that you do more frequent demos. But you may already be doing this, since you didn't mention your current sprint duration.